# Brown and black spots on my fiddle leaf fig?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, figs

My fiddle leaf fig is sitting in a warm, sunny environment next to a large open window. The soil is kept moist, but it sits in a well-drained pot.

It’s getting brown and black spotted marks across the leaves. I’ve never seen this pattern on a plant before. Any suggestions on what it might be or what to check?

My best guess is the brown spots could be sunburn (although it's under the shade most of the day near the large window), and the black spots could be infestation (I may need to check the soil for this?).

View from top
[image]

Close up of leaf damage
[image]

Underside of leaf
[image]

Healthy stem
[image]